# What set does this unopened bag belong to? Lots of grey and brown

Tags: set-identification

[image: lots of grey and brown]

I found this bag number 7, but cannot figure out what Lego set it belongs to.

Answer (score 9):

Based on having a lot of [Light Bley 1x4 with studs on the side](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=30414&colorID=86&in=A) and [black ladder with clips](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=6020&colorID=11&in=A) and a boat steering wheel of some sort, it must be [21310 Old Fishing Store](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=21310-1).

[image: 21130]

Comment: Thank you.  But this set doesn’t look familiar at all.  My kids have never had this type of set. I appreciate any additional help you could give.  Thanks!

Comment: I have looked at all sets that were in production in 2017 (seal code on your bag ends in 7 which means 2017) and that were large enough, AND had Black Plate 4x10 in it, as well as the LBG brick 1x4 with studs on side AND the tan windows, and as @RSchulz already concluded, only 21130 qualifies.

Comment: @PhilB. That number is for **production** date, which doesn't always relate to year set was introduced into market. For example, all sets manufactured for beginning of 2022 will have 2021 marking. Pictured bag could have also been an additional production of something that has been introduced in 2016. Apart from that, spot on!

Comment: @Alex - I never said I looked only at sets that came out in 2017. I said I looked at sets that were IN PRODUCTION in 2017, which indeed includes sets that came out in 2016 and even 2015, and even 2018.

Comment: @PhilB. In case of 21310, yes, it is highly unlikely it was produced in 2016. But I don't think there is a good way of knowing what was in production in 2017. Say 10220, it was available for [over 9 years](https://brickset.com/article/46661). So if you find it sitting on a shelf in 2017 you cannot tell if it was produced same year or sometime in past 6 years.